# Cannot create a Spring bean through a factory method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following config class

```
@Configuration
public class UpdatingBatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public UpdatingBatch updatingBatch(OSRefEnabledFileNetConnectionContext context) {
        return UpdatingBatch.createUpdatingBatchInstance(context,Refreshmode.OFF);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error

```
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.filenet.api.core.UpdatingBatch:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class com.filenet.api.core.UpdatingBatch
```

I do not understand why this is happening. Why is Spring not calling the updatingBatch() method whenever it requires a new UpdatingBatch instance and it is attempting to call the constructor? Isn't this the purpose of decorating methods with the @Bean annotation?

Comment: Have you read the exception? It does call the method but somehow it needs a proxy for the `UpdatingBatch` (due to the step scope). For this it needs either `public` or `protected` constructors on the class.

Comment: M.Deinum yes, I know this. The UpdatingBatch class has no public constructors, but It is a dependency class and I have no way of changing it. Is there no way around this?

Comment: As I stated you need a proxy due to the stepscope, so no there is no way around this, unless removing the step scope is an option but it probably isn't.

Comment: Correct, the real issue here is `@StepScope`, which is equivalent to `@Scope(value="step", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)`, causing the necessity of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments the @Bean and @StepScope won't work in your case. As you can't provide a constructor in a third-party class.

Instead of the above you can create a Component class with a field of type UpdatingBatch and implement a StepListener to create a new instance of UpdatingBatch before each Step run.